# AWS cloudwatch diskspaceavailable alarm setup using AWSCLI

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have already setup a cron job to send diskspaceavailable to cloudwatch metrics but when I try to create cloudwatch alarm for diskspaceavailable, i'm not able to get it to work because of the dimensions that i'm using within the alarm creation.

diskspaceavailable setup commands

```
sudo yum install perl-Switch perl-DateTime perl-Sys-Syslog perl-LWP-Protocol-https perl-Digest-SHA --enablerepo="rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional" -y
sudo yum install wget zip unzip -y
mkdir /tmp/cloudwatch
sudo wget -P /tmp/cloudwatch https://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip
unzip /tmp/cloudwatch/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip
rm -rf /tmp/cloudwatch/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.1.zip
cp ~/.aws/credentials /tmp/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.conf
sed -i '1d' /tmp/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.conf
grep '*/5 * * * * /tmp/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-path=/ --disk-space-avail --disk-space-used --disk-space-units=gigabytes --from-cron' /etc/crontab || echo '*/5 * * * * /tmp/cloudwatch/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-path=/ --disk-space-avail --disk-space-used --disk-space-units=gigabytes --from-cron' > /etc/crontab
```

What would be the right dimensions to use?

```
ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1::cloudwatch"
CPU_USAGE=50
DISKSPACE_AVAILABLE=20
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm ${DRYRUN}\
    --alarm-name "${HN}-diskspaceavailable"\
    --alarm-description "Alarm when disk space less that 20GB"\
    --actions-enabled\
    --ok-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --alarm-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --insufficient-data-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --metric-name DiskSpaceAvailable\
    --namespace System/Linux\
    --statistic Average\
    --dimensions  Name=InstanceId,Value=${INSTANCE_ID}, Name=Filesystem\
    --period 300\
    --threshold ${DISKSPACE_AVAILABLE}\
    --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold\
    --evaluation-periods 1\
    --unit Gigabytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Filesystem_value=$(df -h / | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')

aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm ${DRYRUN}\
    --alarm-name "${HN}-diskspaceavailable"\
    --alarm-description "Alarm when disk space less that 20GB"\
    --actions-enabled\
    --ok-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --alarm-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --insufficient-data-actions "${ARN_OF_SNS_TOPIC}"\
    --metric-name DiskSpaceAvailable\
    --namespace System/Linux\
    --statistic Average\
    --dimensions Name=Filesystem,Value=${Filesystem_value} Name=InstanceId,Value=${INSTANCE_ID} Name=MountPath,Value=/\
    --period 300\
    --threshold ${DISKSPACE_AVAILABLE}\
    --comparison-operator LessThanThreshold\
    --evaluation-periods 1
#    --unit Gigabytes
echo 'cloudwatch disk space available alarm has been created'
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see is that you're missing the value for Filesystem dimension. Should be something like:

```
--dimensions  Name=InstanceId,Value=${INSTANCE_ID}, Name=Filesystem,Value=SOMETHING\
```

You can see the dimensions in the CloudWatch Metrics Console. When you add the metric to the graph, you can hover over the Details column and see all the dimensions.

Comment: Now every after mentioning the instance_id value for the alarm doesn't show up the instance id, when created.
And I have included Filesystem & it's value manually but is there a way to retrive the value without manual intervention. df -h output:

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2   80G  1.5G   79G   2% /

Comment: got the dimensions to work. Just had to remove a , 

--dimensions  Name=InstanceId,Value=${INSTANCE_ID} Name=Filesystem,Value=/dev/nvme0n1p2\

Alarm is still showing insufficient